# 4 handed poker will come to Las Vegas Casinos with the reopening is this good enough?

Tags: gaming-law

Saw on a local youtube video from ["IamnotleavingLasvegas"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QYpX-dMycU&t=512s) a commentary on the Nevada Gaming Rules for casinos to reopen. All areas have to operate at 50% of fire code capacity including poker, and specific to poker games are limited to 4 players. They also have some other things going on with frequency of cleaning of the cards and chips, like your have to sanitized every time they change hands. I guess we will have to wipe down the pots. All this adds up to a lot of time for each hand.

Anyway to the question, aside from the other hassles, is four handed poker enough to get you on a plane headed to Las Vegas to play poker?

Comment: I heard in California casinos may reopen soon but there may not be any poker (or I assume any other table games). Can anybody verify this?

Comment: How good would be "good enough"?

Comment: Now that a year has gone by it turns out they were able to settle on 8 handed games with plastic shields in most NV casinos. I have been playing at Bellagio after getting vac. The plastic is down and most people have unmasked. Turns out 8 handed games are popular with the players and they are going to keep them for awhile longer to see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

With all honestly, if you could find a table with 1 weak player among your 3 opponents, I would MUCH rather play that then 9 handed games.

You will play more pots with them and can take advantage of the situation, so I would surely want to try it out. The biggest question is, how many recreational players will be playing in Vegas when this is over?

Comment: I think it will start really slow. Than comeback over time, not sure if it will comeback the way it was but who knows.

Comment: The problem is that it cost the same for the casino to run 4handed and 9handed games (one dealer + floor space) and I doubt they will be making the same amount of rake, so it is probably not feasible for them in the long run. If the virus goes away entirely, I think everything will return sooner then we think :)

Comment: Cost a little less, two big costs go down with the number of players, drinks and comps. Hourly revenue in a racked game increases if there is no discount, decreases surprisingly little if any with a discount. Short handed games see a lot more hands. They charge by the player for time in Nevada so time games will see a drop in revenue.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely will not get me in the car to go to vegas. I think it is a good way to get dealers and casino employees back at work but there are clear health risks.

As far as playing live 4-handed goes, I do not see it as a huge impediment to poker players. Players who tend to play tighter and have less experience will probably not be able to do very well at these tables, but players who are comfortable playing wider ranges and dealing with aggression will be the most likely to excel. Players will also be playing the blinds more often, this may not appeal to players because they will be paying rake more often. The casinos will be taking the same amount of rake at more hands per hour. I personally would need to practice short handed poker before I felt comfortable playing this table regularly.

Comment: Nevada, at where I work, the rake is a percentage of the pot. Higher limits pay time but it is collected by the dealer when they sit down. They discount rake automatically when the game gets short handed. Currently (or when it shut down) 1-3 rake was 10% to $5 max discount was one dollar off at 6,5 and 4 handed. But whom knows if they will be able to continue to do this.

Comment: There are clear health risks. There is nothing possible like social distancing at a poker table. I am hoping they just open with slots so they can keep floating longer and have good social distancing. I would also like to see masks required for customers. I don't plan on going back to the casino, working or playing until this thing has passed.